# How to append data to a table (Script to HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript in order to append data to my table.

[image]

As you see the above image everything works out but when i append it the the table.The table is not been show on my HTML page.

Java script

```
success: function (data) {
            var inquirieslist = JSON.stringify(data)
            $.each(inquirieslist, function (index, item) { //the code which comes here is at the bottom

                $('<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + item.ReservationDate + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.Name1 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.Name2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.VenueName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.PackageTypeName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.IsActive + '</td>'+
                    '</tr>').appendTo($('#grid'));

            });
            }
```

**$.each(inquirieslist, function (index, item) {**`index = 0, item = {ReservationDate: "/Date(1585852200000)/", ReservationNo: "RA00006", Name1: "", Name2: "PALIHAWADANA", VenueName: "Windsor", …}`

This is my HTML that im using.

```
<div class="row grid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card m-b-30">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="card-title">Reservations</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="grid" style="display:none;">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Reservation Date</th>
                            <th>Name1</th>
                            <th>Name2</th>
                            <th>Venue</th>
                            <th>Package</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th width="90px"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Active / Inactive">Completed</span></th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr class="no-record">
                            <td colspan="4">No Records Found.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when ever i append my table it not drawn or shown on my HTML page.Is this wrong or am i missing something.
Im still a beginner.

Comment: Is `style="display:none;"` still there?

Comment: when you are changing this  style="display:none;" to visible ?

Comment: @acbay I just removed it from my other pages would it work if i remove this?

Comment: @SivaRmK i Have not done it yet ,would it work if i remove this?

Comment: yes it is try once and see the result

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link use `interpolation` to append tr to table: `$('#grid tr:last').after(`...`)`

Also need remove display none for your table `style="display:none;"`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56096496/4964569

```
     $.each(inquirieslist, function (index, item) { //

     $('#grid tr:last').after(`<tr><td>${item.ReservationDate}</td><td>${item.Name1}</td><td>${item.Name2}</td><td>${item.VenueName}</td><td>${item.PackageTypeName}</td><td>${item.IsActive}</td></tr>`)

   });
```

```js
var inquirieslist = [{
  ReservationDate: '2020/04/21',
  Name1: 'A',
  Name2: 'A',
  VenueName: 'C',
  PackageTypeName: 'D',
  IsActive: true
},
{
ReservationDate: '2020/04/21',
  Name1: 'A',
  Name2: 'A',
  VenueName: 'C',
  PackageTypeName: 'D',
  IsActive: true
}];
            $.each(inquirieslist, function (index, item) { //
            
                $('#grid tr:last').after(`<tr><td>${item.ReservationDate}</td><td>${item.Name1}</td><td>${item.Name2}</td><td>${item.VenueName}</td><td>${item.PackageTypeName}</td><td>${item.IsActive}</td></tr>`)

            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row grid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card m-b-30">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="card-title">Reservations</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="grid">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Reservation Date</th>
                            <th>Name1</th>
                            <th>Name2</th>
                            <th>Venue</th>
                            <th>Package</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th width="90px"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Active / Inactive">Completed</span></th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr class="no-record">
                            <td colspan="4">No Records Found.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [add-table-row-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

```
$('#myTable > tbody:first').append('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

as opposed to

```
$('#myTable > tbody:last').append('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```